# MongoDB connection not established

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

While I try to connect to MongoDB this error pops up:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas 
cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at _handleConnectionErrors (D:\Practice\express_new\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (D:\Practice\express_new\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:767:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)    
    at async connectDB (D:\Practice\express_new\index.js:7:5) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-usnm8db-shard-00-01.ahkcsoe.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-usnm8db-shard-00-00.ahkcsoe.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-usnm8db-shard-00-02.ahkcsoe.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-idl89b-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

This is the code snippet link:

https://github.com/0plaze0/mongoDB/blob/60d03aeb2ca67196e13df3d5dcea3e48e0c48105/server.js#L63

I have replaced the password, user and also the IP is 0.0.0.0/0 in network access.

I am following a tutorial from Dave Gray on mongoDB.

Comment: The provided code does not match the error message, please review it. You should print the real error message `err.message` rather than just `"no connection"` which does not provide any information why it is failing.

Comment: `One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/`... You need to whitelist your IP in MongoAtlas.

Comment: this is the code https://github.com/0plaze0/mongoDB/blob/60d03aeb2ca67196e13df3d5dcea3e48e0c48105/server.js#L63  @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: @PRATHEESHPC doesn't 0.0.0.0 includes my I.P. also

Comment: Don't expect us to browse all your code. Apart from that, you disclosed your credentials to public - **I can connect to your MongoDB!** works without any problem. Maybe your firewall blocks the outgoing traffic.

Comment: should i disable the firewall and try or their any other way

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thankyou error is fixed